# ¿Cómo exportar un componente VUE para usarlo como IIFE?

Tags: vue3, paquetes-npm

Tengo una aplicación realizada con webpack npm, quisiera exportar un componente para usarlo desde un archivo fuera del entorno.

Algo como esto:

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@3.1.1"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/echarts@5.1.2"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue-echarts@6.0.0-rc.6"></script>
```

¿Cuál es la mejor forma de realizarlo?

Comment: No esta claro lo que necesitas. ¿Quisieras saber como crear un paquete para luego poder instalarlo con `npm`?

Answer (score 1):

Entiendo que lo que quieres hacer es empaquetar un componente de Vue y publicarlo en npm o usarlo de forma local importandolo con la etiqueta .
La cli te provee comandos para poder hacer build de un componente.
Esta informacion se encuentra en la documentacion [build targets](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/build-targets.html).

Si iniciaste tu proyecto usando la vue/cli con

```
vue create nombreDelproyecto
```

Segun la documentación, podemos usar vue-cli-service para empaquetar nuestro componente como una libreria o como un WebComponent. La diferencia entre ambos es que una libreria está hecha para ser usada en un proyecto de Vue, en cambio un WebComponent se puede usar en cualquier lado, ya que se empaqueta con lo necesario de Vue, al menos eso es lo que yo entendí.

```
vue-cli-service build --target lib --name nombreQueLeDaremos './src/components/rutaDelComponente.vue'
```

Si no te funciona por un error de vue/compiler-sfc, prueba añadir esto a tu package.json

```
"buildComponente": "vue-cli-service build --target lib --name nombreQueLeDaremos './src/components/rutaDelComponente.vue'"
```

y luego corre en la consola

```
npm run buildComponente
```

El componente empaquetado debería quedar en la carpeta dist, luego debemos publicarlo en npm para poder hacer uso de el.

Este ejemplo que te di lo puse en practica y funcionó perfectamente, sin problemas.
Si es que estás usando Vite, podrías ver este [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5QV9wVc8c7g)